# How to get Sub Domain on Web API Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, subdomain

I am developing a `Classified Web Site`. This web site has a lot of Sub Domains like `dubai.sitedomain.com`, `london.sitedomain.com`, `newyork.sitedomain.com` etc depending on cities. I am using `Angularjs` as my front end and `Web Api` as server side.

My requirement is I want to get the `subdomain` on my `Web Api Action`. Like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAds")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAds()
    {
        // Here I want to know, from which subdomain the request has been sent
        // so I can filter my ads according to the city
        var city = "city from subdomain";
        var list = _adService.GetAdsByCity(city);

        return Ok(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Request.Headers.Referrer.Host.Replace(".sitedomain.com", string.Empty);`

Of course this will only work on your live environment, so you may need to modify this to work differently on your local test domains, or provide some sort of default fallback. I would suggest extracting this to a method in a common library, as it's likely you will need it in many places.

Alternatively, if you know that it will always be the first part, you can use

`Request.Headers.Referrer.Host.Substring(0, Request.Headers.Referrer.Host.IndexOf("."));`

Comment: Apologies, didn't see that you were using Web API rather than MVC. Corrected to show `RequestUri` instead.

Comment: Request.RequestUri.Host gives my address of the Web Api not client, But Request.Headers.Referrer.Host did the trick for me. Your answer leads me to this solution. Thanks :) +1

Comment: Thanks, if my answer is correct, please mark as accepted. It may also be useful for you to mention in your question that your API is hosted on a different domain to the requesting website, as I had assumed that they were hosted under one ASP.NET process (Web API can be hosted within an MVC website with an Angular frontend without any issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it from

```
var x = Request.Host.Value;
```

Which will give you "london.sitedomain.com:port"

You can then do a

```
x.Split('.')[0] //(for example)
```

To get the subdomain

Comment: Syntax Error : Host is not recognized.

Comment: Ah, it's asp.net 5 specific, (haven't used 4.5< in a while). May want to specify which version you're using in the question

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5, Web Api 2.2

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
```

There is also:

```
Request.Url.Scheme
Request.Url.Authority
Request.ApplicationPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get host from `HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri.Host`:

```cs
string host = Request.RequestUri.Host;
int index = host.IndexOf('.');

return host.Substring(0, index + 1)
```